# How can I correctly name my restful resources?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I am developing a classified site.I am using spring framework for developing restful apis.My restful resource name for getting all the ads is:

```
localhost:8081/v1/ads
```

Similarly,when I want to get all the featured ads.I want to name it like

```
localhost:8081/v1/ads?featured=true
```

My rest controller is

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ads",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<Ad>> getAllFeaturedAds(@RequestParam("status) Boolean status throws SQLException {
    List<Ad> allFeaturedAds = adService.findAllFeaturedAds(status);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Ad>>(allFeaturedAds,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But I am getting an error because the url for both the methods is same.Solution is to use the name as

```
localhost:8081/v1/ads/featured
```

But this does not match the restful naming convention.So,what should I do to use the url as:

```
localhost:8081/v1/ads?featured=true
```

Comment: you mention 'both' methods, but you've only shown one. what does the first one look like?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/ads",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json",headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Ad> insert(@RequestBody Ad ad) throws SQLException {
        return new ResponseEntity<Ad>((Ad)adService.insert(ad), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

Comment: Most likely, you forgot to include the `params` attribute in your mapping. Note that the `produces` is nearly always redundant (Spring will content-negotiate automatically), as is the `ResponseEntity` if the only thing you're doing is setting an HTTP status (OK is the default, you can annotate a status on the method, or you can throw an exception with an error status).

Comment: @pravin edit your original post with this other method. will help people see your entire problem.